# DatabaseFactory and output parameter

Tags: asp.net, enterprise-library

I've started using Enterprise Library and have the following questions:

1)How do I add output parameter to this query and how do I get it back:

```
public int InsertDoc(HDocument document)
{          
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();  
    int result;
    var reader = db.ExecuteNonQuery("sp_InsertDocument", 
                document.AddedDate,document.AddedBy, document.Title))         
     .
     .
     .
}
```

The db.AddOutParameter requires paremetrers that I don't have like DbCommand.

2)I have a few methods that work with database (I transfer from ADO.net) stored procedures,
 do I have to declare :  Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(); in each one of them or I can reuse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) - You can make a DbCommand thusly:

```
DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetSqlStringCommand("sp_InsertDocument");
```

and retrieve the output parameter after execution with:

```
db.GetParameterValue(dbCommand, "outputParameterName");
```

Here's a good example of using EntLib to execute a sproc with output params:
http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/30910/0/page/4

2) - You can use DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase() in each method, that's fine. EntLib will manage the connections as necessary.
As an aside, if you're only using the db variable once in a method, then you could simplify your code slightly by using an inline temp instead of declaring a variable, i.e.:

```
var reader = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase().ExecuteNonQuery(....
```